# Create/Initialize a List of controls one time in static class

Tags: c#, class, static, constructor, factory

Should I do this in a static Ctor? Else if the Create method is public static everyone could call it and recreate the List of controls. That is not wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my public Get I would just check if my list of objects is empty and create it there before return it back to the caller. Don't forget to `lock` this part of code, to insure that only the first call on your empty list does the create.

Comment: you mean this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx ??? why should I lock the creating of a menu control?

Comment: you need to lock it because if your instance's Get property is accessed from 2 different threads at the same time, you might end that both of them will try to create your menu with unexpected results. If your instance will be accessed from a single thread you don't need that.

Comment: the code runs in a asp.net application so... the dummy is right :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you intend to do (your question is pretty vague), but if you want to make sure your initialization is executed once and only once before any call to any member of your class, the static constructor is the place to go.

Comment: build together a list of menuItems append them at a ContextMenu and return that with a public Get method. till now the ContextMenu was created in the Get method so created multiple times...